# Error while trying to bind SystemVerilog module with properties module

Tags: system-verilog, intel-fpga, quartus, verification, systemverilog-assertions

I have a SystemVerilog module that I want to test using assertions. For simplicity let's say the DUT is this:

```vhdl
module dut (
    input logic [7:0] da
    output logic [7:0] db
);

    always_comb begin:
        if (da == '0)
            db <= '1;
        else
            db <= '0
    end
endmodule
```

I have also created a file containing a module with the assertions for the DUT:

```vhdl
module properties(
    input logic [7:0] pa,
    input logic [7:0] pb
);

    always_comb begin:
        assert final (pa == pb) $error("assertion failed"); else $display("PASS");
    end

endmodule
```

And finally I have a test bench:

```vhdl
module tb();

    logic [7:0] ta;
    logic [7:0] tb;

    dut dut_inst(.da(ta), .db(tb));

    bind dut_inst properties dut_bind(.pa(da), .pb(db));

    initial begin:

       // do something here...

    end

endmodule
```

**The problem**: When compiling the code I get two errors from Quartus :

- The first one is about the properties module and says: `Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at properties.sv(6) near text: "final";  expecting "(".` If I remove the `final` keyword the error goes away but I must use final to filter out simulation glitches.
- The second one says `Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at tb.sv(8) near text: "bind";  expecting "endmodule".`

**What I have tried so far**

Regarding the first issue I only tried to remove the `final` keyword but it is not a solution as I said before.

For the second error, I tried binding this way:

```vhdl
bind dut properties dut_bind(.pa(da), .pb(db));
```

but I get the same error. I also tried moving the bind out of the `tb` module like that:

```vhdl
module tb();

    logic [7:0] ta;
    logic [7:0] tb;

    dut dut_inst(.da(ta), .db(tb));

    initial begin:

       // do something here...

    end

endmodule

bind dut properties dut_bind(.pa(da), .pb(db));
```

but I got a similar error saying `Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at tb.sv(8) near text: "bind";  expecting a description.` What am I doing wrong?

PS: I am using intel Quartus Prime lite edition.

Comment: What tool are you trying to use? Assertions are for simulation or formal checking tools, not synthesis.

Comment: @dave_59 I use modelsim for simulation and intel Quartus Prime lite edition for synthesis. I was under the impression that assertions where synthesisable

Comment: Is the error coming from modelsim or quartus?

Comment: `syntax error at properties.sv(6) near text: "final";` is odd: Does line counting start at zero?

Comment: The error is coming from quartus and the syntax error is on the line `assert final (pa == pb)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind syntax:  `bind dut : dut_inst properties dut_bind (.pa(da), .pb(db));`

Place it inside the testbench module after instantiating the DUT.

Since Quartus tool is for synthesis, use a compiler directive to let the synthesis tool skip the assertion.

Example:

```
module tb();

    logic [7:0] ta;
    logic [7:0] tb;

    dut dut_inst(.da(ta), .db(tb));

// if SYNTHESIS is not defined, include below code  
`ifndef SYNTHESIS
    bind dut : dut_inst properties dut_bind (.pa(da), .pb(db));
`endif
// end if
    initial begin

       // do something here...

    end

endmodule
```

Pass `SYNTHESIS` as a compilation option during synthesis to let the tool skip the assertion.

Comment: What is and how do I use the directive you mentioned?

Comment: @KyriafinisVasilis updated my answer

Comment: @KyriafinisVasilis since Quartus is for synthesis, don't include testbench in it. Please accept my answer if that helped!

Comment: I surrounded the bind with the `// synthesis translate_off` `// synthesis translate_on` directives and Quartus synthesized the code but now I have problems on modelsim saying `Error: (vsim-3033) Instantiation of 'properties' failed. The design unit was not found.`. I suspect it is because the design was not synthesized

Comment: Also, I don't use the testbench as the top module and I have it set up in Quartus as a testbench for the dut

Comment: So you got your Quartus synthesis working. The error from modelsim looks to me a separate question. Please ask it in a separate question. The current question is on Quartus Prime.